# Azure AD Add AppRoleAssignment

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, rbac, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD for the authentication service on an MVC application. I am managing the user accounts successfully using the Graph API. I am trying to add an `AppRoleAssignment` to the user.

```
string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceID);
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantID);
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetTokenForApplication());

IUser user = new User();
user.JobTitle = "Tester";
user.DisplayName = "Test Tester";
user.Surname = "Tester";
user.GivenName = "Test";
user.UserPrincipalName = "ttester@test.com";
user.AccountEnabled = true;
user.MailNickname = "ttester";
user.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
{
    Password = "XXXXX",
    ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = true
};
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user);

var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment
{
    Id = Guid.Parse("XXXXX"),
    ResourceId = Guid.Parse("XXXXX"),
    PrincipalType = "User",
    PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(user.ObjectId)
};

user.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);
await user.UpdateAsync();
```

The `AppRoleAssignment` is never made. I am not certain if it is the constructor variables.

The `id` I am placing the `ID` of the role, being created in the application manifest. The `ResourceId` I am placing the `ObjectId` of the application. The application is created under the AAD Directory.

The code actually completes without error, however inspecting the user it shows not `AppRoleAssignments`.

In the end I am trying to implement RBAC using application roles.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To assign application role to a user, you need to cast the `User` object to `IUserFetcher`:

```
await ((IUserFetcher)user)
    .AppRoleAssignments.AddAppRoleAssignmentAsync(appRoleAssignment);
```

I also had to set the ResourceId to the `ServicePrincipal.ObjectId`

```
var servicePrincipal = (await
            activeDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals.Where(
                s => s.DisplayName == "MyApplicationName").ExecuteAsync()).CurrentPage
            .First();

var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment
{
    Id = Guid.Parse("XXXXX"),
    // Service principal id go here
    ResourceId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId),
    PrincipalType = "User",
    PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(user.ObjectId)
};
```

Comment: I am going to try this out. Curious, when you get your `User` object is the `AppRoles` property populated. I found in my code, it is actually assigning it to the AppRole. However the property even on a subsequent retrieval is still null.